# Installing any APP hardboots phone and bootloops

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, oneplus-one

I have a Oneplus 1 running CM11 44s Kitkat 4.4.4

I did a clean flash of CM11 and now I am unable to install any app from playstore.
As soon as an app finishes installing, the phone hardboots and enters bootloop or I get continuous error messages Trebuchet stops working, Play Store stopped working

I have to goto Safe Mode and unistall app to recover phone.

Apps which I have tried to install and have been unsuccessful
Greenify
Nova Launcher
Facebook
Gboard
Microsoft SMS Organiser

Basically, I am unable to install anything at all! All these were running fine before, now dont understand whats wrong!

I cleaned whole phone, formatted all with fastboot and reinstalled CM11, but the problem remains.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it is the FaceBook app that causes the bootloop. I have CM11 on a Nexus 7. I used the Play store to update a few apps last week and when I came back to it, it was looping. I did several factory resets and found it was the latest FB app. I get an instant bootloop on installing. I just decided not to use it :)  Of course whatever the issue is (maybe some issue Android Studio is introducing that CM11 does not like) may affect other apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's becouse appt2 someone posted about it in google's issue tracker here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64434571#comment22 and they say they would release an update to appt2 to fix the problem it happens to all CyanogenMod/LineageOS Rom and they descriped the bug in detail too here is it :-
CyanogenMod has this function getPkgName (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-13.0/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp).  It creates a ResXMLTree on the stack and points it at a buffer from an asset without making a copy.  Then it closes the asset before the ResXMLTree is destroyed.

For apps built by aapt, this is benign.  However, aapt2 produces UTF-8 string pools, which cause the ResXMLTree's ResStringPool(mStrings)'s mCache to become non-null in ResStringPool::stringAt (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-13.0/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp).  Then ResStringPool::uninit dereferences mHeader (which is now dangling), and a crash ensues.

This crash shows up in different ways.  On one Cyanogen OS device, the launcher crashes when an app built with aapt2 has been installed, but only if the manifest is large (probably due to how deallocation happens for small vs large blobs).  On another device, system_server crashes at boot if an aapt2-built app is installed.

We're attempting to work around this with a custom build of aapt2 that always produces a UTF-16 string pool for the manifest.  Results so far are promising.